# How do I sort a list of class instances(objects) based on multiple values of the objects in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have a list of objects, each object is an instance of a class and has 5 values each. I need to sort the list based on two values. i.e. firstname and lastname. How can I do that? Or is there a better way to achieve what I am doing?

Also is there a way to list all the objects of this list in json format after sorting?

```
class Format1():
    def __init__(self, alist):
        self.color = alist[3]
        self.firstname = alist[1]
        self.lastname = alist[0]
        self.phonenumber = alist[2]
        self.zipcode = alist[4] 

obj = Format1(alist)
entries.append(obj)
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: obj = Format1(alist)
entries.append(obj)

class Format1():
 def __init__(self, alist):
  self.color = alist[3]
  self.firstname = alist[1]
  self.lastname = alist[0]
  self.phonenumber = alist[2]
  self.zipcode = alist[4]

So I am creating multiple objects using the above class and adding the objects to the list.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code?

Comment: Also, yes, custom key function for sort, and yes, look at the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sorting, You can use `sorted()` function with `key` argument as -

```
sortedlist = sorted(alist, key=lambda x: (x.firstname , x.lastname))
```

Also, if by json format , you mean something like -

```
{'color':'<colorname>', 'firstname','<firstname>' ....}
```

Such a dictionary for each object. Then you can create a function that returns the `__dict__` attribute of the object and use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) and `map` like -

```
def cdict(a):
    return a.__dict__

s = json.dumps(list(map(cdict,<your list>)))
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted = sorted(alist, key=lambda x: (x['firstname'], x['lastname']))
```

Comment: You're assuming that he has implemented a __getitem__ method. He isn't storing this data in json, so this code would not work for what he currently has, code-wise.

Comment: True. Getting __getitem__ error on using the above method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Kremlan's answer, add the following to your class:

```
    def __getitem__(self, option):
        return {"color": self.color,
                "firstname": self.firstname,
                "lastname": self.lastname
                "phonenumber": self.phonenumber
                "zipcode": self.zipcode
        }.get(option.lower(), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to make things a bit more descriptive/readable

```
import operator
last_then_first = operator.attrgetter('lastname', 'firstname')
entries.sort(key = last_then_first)
```